# Get reference to trait defined inside object

Tags: scala

Have following code and having trouble figuring out how to implement (mainly get access ) and execute trait's method "toTest" which is defined inside object.

```
object Main extends App {

    object A {
       trait Test[T] {
          def toTest(in: T): String

       def apply[T: Test](in: T): String = implicitly[Test[T]].toTest(in)
   }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what you're trying to accomplish just by looking at the snippet. Can you add an example of how you wish to "execute trait's method "toTest""?

Comment: from command line with just a test string and basically just print it out ...  scala com.test.Main "Test string"

Comment: my problem is trait is defined inside object .... if it were defined outside I wouldn't be asking anything here

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: "Does it solve your problem?" ...of course not ... I have code given as it is and that's why I asked for help here

Comment: Aleksey Izmailov ...I am sorry I missed you answer below :-) ...Yes it does solve it!...Thank you

Comment: np @Guy1212 I edited it like 3 times :)

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov pretty funny. Actually, possibly a flaw in SO workflow or notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmodified code:

```
scala> object Main extends App {
     | 
     |     object A {
     |        trait Test[T] {
     |           def toTest(in: T): String
     | 
     |        def apply[T: Test](in: T): String = implicitly[Test[T]].toTest(in)
     |    }
     | }
     | }
defined module Main

scala> new Main.A.Test[Int]{ override def toTest(in: Int) = in.toString }.toTest(123)
res0: String = 123
```

Simplified:

```
scala> object Main extends App {
     | 
     |     object A {
     |        trait Test[T] {
     |           def toTest(in: T): String
     | 
     |           def apply(in: T): String = toTest(in)
     |        }
     |     }
     | }
defined module Main

scala> new Main.A.Test[Int]{ override def toTest(in: Int) = in.toString }.toTest(123)
res2: String = 123

scala> (new Main.A.Test[Int]{ override def toTest(in: Int) = in.toString })(123)
res6: String = 123
```